# django--LayerMapError: Could not retrieve geometry from feature

Tags: python, django, postgresql

.

i got this error when i run my apps in django..it says
LayerMapError: Could not retrieve geometry from feature

i have already created spatial database in postgresql (following the tutorial given in [[this tutorial]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#tutorial) )

below is my load.py code 
and my models.py
my app name is Application_Files
and my module name is mod_parcel

```
import os

from django.contrib.gis.utils import LayerMapping
from models import mod_parcel

bound_mapping = {
'NEWPIN' : 'NEWPIN',
'DIST_NO' : 'DIST_NO',
'TDNO' : 'TDNO',
'PIN' : 'PIN',
'OWNERFULLN': 'OWNERFULLN',
'AREA' : 'AREA',
'OCT_TCNO' : 'OCT_TCNO',
'BARANGAY' : 'BARANGAY',
'CLASS' : 'CLASS',
'MRKTVAL' : 'MRKTVAL',
'ASSDVAL' : 'ASSDVAL',
'Geometry' : 'Geometry',
}

bound_shp = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'DATA/parcel/parcels.shp'))

def run(verbose=True):
lm = LayerMapping(mod_parcel, bound_shp, bound_mapping,
                  transform=False, encoding='iso-8859-1')
lm.save(strict=True, verbose=verbose)
```

another code is in here. .

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gismodels

class mod_parcel(gismodels.Model):

NEWPIN = gismodels.CharField(max_length=35)
DIST_NO = gismodels.IntegerField()
TDNO = gismodels.CharField(max_length=254)
PIN = gismodels.CharField(max_length=254)
OWNERFULLN = gismodels.CharField(max_length=254)
AREA = gismodels.FloatField()
OCT_TCNO = gismodels.CharField(max_length=254)
BARANGAY = gismodels.CharField(max_length=254)
CLASS = gismodels.CharField(max_length=254)
MRKTVAL = gismodels.FloatField()
ASSDVAL = gismodels.FloatField()
Geometry = gismodels.MultiPolygonField(srid=32651)
objects = gismodels.GeoManager()

def __unicode__(self):
return self.NEWPIN
```

I dont really know where to modify codes or something. . its just that i am a newbie in django and i cannot figure this out.. can any share something relevant to this problem??

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your geometry setting in the mapping.
It is expecting an OGRGeomType such as POINT, POLYGON....

Comment: thank you. . i think i really need to work out more on the data entry such as this. . really appreciate you giving hints. . ☺ ☺ ☺